# Start android activity in existing proccess

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

My Android application starts a local foreground service (in the same process as my activity). 
However, the system destroys the activity due low memory, but the foreground service remains alive.

Next time the user starts the app, it starts a new process. 
Is there a way for my existing foreground service to be bound to this newly created process, and not the old destroyed one?

One option I thought is to adopt Inter-process communication, which I would like to *avoid* due to high complexity. Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: "it starts a new process" -- not normally. The only reason why it would do that is if you are using `android:process` attributes in your manifest. If you are, and you do not want them, get rid of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) for a cue.

From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html):

> By default, all components of the same application run in the same
>   process and thread (called the "main" thread). If an application
>   component starts and there already exists a process for that
>   application (because another component from the application exists),
>   then the component is started within that process and uses the same
>   thread of execution.

It behaves as expected. I am beginner in android development and did not know that.

Second time I started application as debug from Android Studio and it recreated process. This is why I got confused.